# helm ls fails with timeout / context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

```
$ helm2 version --debug

Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.10", 
GitCommit:"bceca24a91639f045f22ab0f41e47589a932cf5e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '34073'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:34073"

Kubernetes: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.11-eks-14f01f", GitCommit:"14f01fe8f04411d5e187b220034ca2117d79f7de", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-23T21:32:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

127.0.0.1:34073[debug] context deadline exceeded
Error: cannot connect to Tiller
```

helm3 gives empty list as well

```
$ helm ls -a                                    
NAME  NAMESPACE REVISION  UPDATED STATUS  CHART APP VERSION
```

```
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get pods -n kube-system | grep tiller                                     
tiller-deploy-69849bbd9-9lw6z           1/1     Running   0          31d
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get deployments -n kube-system | grep tiller
tiller-deploy          1/1     1            1           402d
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get sa -n kube-system | grep tiller  
tiller                               1         402d
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get clusterrole -n kube-system | grep tiller
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get clusterrolebinding -n kube-system | grep tiller
tiller                                                 402d
(⎈ |arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:xxx:cluster/xxx:default)
code on  master [!?] 
➜ k get service -n kube-system | grep tiller           
tiller-deploy          ClusterIP   10.100.23.25     <none>        44134/TCP       402d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution**

Turns out the tiller was deployed with SSL certs that you need to pass.

```sh
~/Development/tools/helm-2.14.2/helm list \
  --tiller-connection-timeout 30 \
  --tls \
  --tls-ca-cert ssl/tiller/tiller-ca.crt \
  --tls-cert ssl/tiller/tiller.crt \
  --tls-key ssl/tiller/tiller.key \
  --all \
  --tiller-namespace kube-system
```

To obtain the certs you have to do this:

```
export TILLER_NAMESPACE="kube-system"

kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode > ssl/tiller/tiller-ca.crt
kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['tls\.crt']}" | base64 --decode > ssl/tiller/tiller.crt
kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['tls\.key']}" | base64 --decode > ssl/tiller/tiller.key
```